# escaping awk with remote ssh command and bash that is already escaped

Tags: bash, bash-scripting, awk

Hello.

```
ssh ufk@10.0.0.2  "bash -lc 'pm2 list | grep app | awk { print $3} '"
```

I need to run the command I pasted here. the problem is that i'm already escaping twice... the bash with `"` and the pm2 with `'`. how can i escape awk ?

i know that it will work if i escape it with awk '{ print $3 }' but the all command is already escaped twice... so .. what do i do ?

## update

i created the following bash command:

```
PM2_APP_ID=`$REMOTE_SRV_SSH_COMMAND "bash -lc \"pm2 list | grep app | grep -v 'pm2 show' | awk '{ print \\\$4 }'\""`;
```

here i get the all pm2 list relevant line, it's like awk is never been executed.

Comment: `awk` can do most cases of `grep` and you don't really need those done remotely, so `ssh u@h "bash -lc 'pm2 list' " | awk '/app/{print $3}'` will also work

Comment: thanks @dave_thompson_085, you helped me resolve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks @dave_thompson_085 for your comment, that helped me resolve the issue.

i'm using the following command:

```
PM2_APP_ID=`$REMOTE_SRV_SSH_COMMAND "bash -lc 'pm2 list'" | grep app | grep -v 'pm2 show' | awk '{ print $4 }'`;
```

as you can see here i use pm2 list on remove server, and the rest i'm doing locally. no hassle with escaping things and it works properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't backslash-escape single quotes inside single-quoted strings, but you can backslash-escape double quotes inside a double-quoted string. So you could do this:

```
ssh ufk@10.0.0.2  "bash -lc \"pm2 list | grep app | awk '{ print \\\$3 }'\""
```

You need to escape the $ in the awk program twice to avoid the $3 from being expanded, first by local shell and then by the remote one.

Comment: trying to test it.. i still get the all line from 'grep app', it's like awk is not being called at all

Comment: @ufk: Sorry. Edited the answer to include necessary backslashes

Comment: updated main post. still not working. thanks for help so far